# Trouble with linking a library - Eclipse

Tags: c, compiler-errors, linker, eclipse-cdt

I have a library in my `.c`:

`#include "Madlib.h"`

I know that now I gotta link it, otherwise it doesn't work. My trouble is understanding HOW do I link it. Every post I see talks about `.a` libraries or with a `lib`prefix. I got none of that. I have the header obvisouly and then a `.lib`.

Anyways, I tried to make my way into those posts, and got here:

[image: Add library]

Although, when I try to compile, I get this:

```
Invoking: Cygwin C Linker
gcc  -o "MCL.exe" ./src/example.o    -lMADLib.lib
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lMADLib.lib: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What exactly is that path? How can I expand it? Should I place the `.lib` and `.h` inside the folder that it refers to? Or should I add some kind of path to the library `-I` entry?

Comment: Try it without `.lib` at the end. (On linux i have to compile it with `-l<libraryName>` without the `.so` (The `.so` exist on the file)).

Comment: Does it work on the terminal? Can you try the simpler way of only using the command line, without any (complex) IDE first?

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 it appears that without `.lib` has worked! Thank you so so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to do 2 things:

- Add the library without the extensions, like `-lMADLib` instead of `-lMADLib.lib`
- As Pierre Bourgery, in case the library isn't in a path where the linker searches through, add the path to the folder where the library is to the library search path, like `-L<path to library folder>`

See here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html

Comment: I might have a different problem now. When I said it worked, i meant that the compilation worked. But when I try to run it, it says after half a sec: `<terminated> (exit value: -1073.741.515`. And it really shouldn't. I tried to run it with Debug with breakpoint and it says `'Launching MCL Debug' has encountered a problem. Error in final launch sequence: Failed to execute MI command: -exec-run`. Do you have any idea what's this?

Comment: @ATSlooking4things If an answer solves the Problem you asked, upvote it and accept it. If you encounter a different problem. ask a new question.

Comment: I always do, just forgot this time. And I already did create another post a couple hours ago.

Answer (score 0):

Try compiling using this flag -I./include

Comment: Shouldn't this be `-L` instead of `-l`, to add a folder to the search path? See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).